# Diffraction and interference of waves explained through photonic theory

Tags: visible-light, photons

I was under the impression that only wave theory of light was able to explain the ideas of diffraction and interference, until I encountered this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=6s&v=Xdlr6yJLyaE .

Now owing to the above video which has left me quite puzzled. Is the the fact true that one can explain diffraction and interference through the photonic theory of light coupled with a very thin layer of fluid coating all interfaces between states of matter?

The explanation in the video gives a very pleasing answer to why light bends around my finger the way it does, and why it changes if I hold my finger near a heat source and also why it changes when I bring other fingers close to it without touching it, or forming a slit like setup.

**Edit:** https://www.natureoflight-particleonly.com/properties-of-fluid-layer link to his description of the fluid.

Comment: Random YouTube videos probably aren't the best place to learn physics. But, given your explanation of the 'theory' - one can often get a new 'theory' to agree with some experiments if you just add something. But, why do you need to posit an ad hoc 'very thin layer of fluid'? What is the fluid, what are its properties, how thin is it? There is no such fluid, it was just needed to make the math kind of work out. Since there is no such fluid, the theory is bunk.

Comment: @JonCuster He explains in his video the details of the fluid layer. How exactly can you claim that there is no fluid, and how exactly does he claim that there is a fluid, is one dillema I'm still in. However assuming his hypothesis is true one may predict the above. Could you please elaborate more on how you immediately jumped to the conclusion that there is no fluid?

Comment: Photons (of various energies), electrons, ions, neutrons, and a wide range of surface imaging techniques all fail to see any signs of a 'very thin layer of fluid' on surfaces. It isn't there. Period.

Comment: Debaditya, the evidence for “How exactly can you claim that there is no fluid,...” is given for experiments with electrons. They have to be carried out in vacuum and no gas nor fluid is between the edges and the electron beam. About these moments experiments see https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges

Comment: [Corpuscular theory of light and Double slit experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/382795)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'm sorry but I'm not able to see how that is evidence. Could you please be a little more explicit? Your paper's first observation mentions the fact that electrons and photons diffract in different manners near and edge. The theorized fluid layer might have too behave differently with different substances.